# PHPMailer SMTP Failed to connect to server: Connection timed out (110) to Gmail

Tags: php, email, smtp, gmail, phpmailer

Im using PHPMailer to connect to Gmails MX server, `gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com`, on port `465`. This errors out `Failed to connect to server: Connection timed out (110)`

After reading online, I just had a chat with my host who successfully ran a `traceroute to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com` on port `25` and I was assured that connections were not being blocked by anything on the host side.

Do I need to set up anything in my gmail account? I am able to connect to other domains via SMTP.

---

I can ALSO connect to `smtp.gmail.com` on `465`, but there the following command does not seem to work right

```
RCPT TO: <wrong.email@gmail.com>
```

gives me a `250` ok.

**EDIT:**
and im using dns_get_record() to get MX record for domains.

this is part of the extended PHPMailer class that i wrote:

```
$this->IsSMTP(); 
$this->Host       = $this->data['smtp_host'];
$this->Mailer   = "smtp";
$this->Timeout      = 10;
$this->SMTPDebug  = 2;
$this->SMTPAuth   = true;
$this->Port       = 465;
$this->Username   = 'my.address@gmail.com';
$this->Password   = 'my_password';

$ret[] = $this->smtpConnect();
$ret[] = $this->smtp->mail('my.address@gmail.com');
$ret[] = $this->smtp->recipient('wrong.email@gmail.com');
$this->smtpClose();
```

the above on ssl://gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com:465 errors out with Connection timed out (110)

on ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465 says 250 Ok, where I should get no such user.

Comment: if you are setting the two-step verification in your gmail account try to desactivate it also in the gmail setting check the transfert pop/imap it should be active !!

Comment: I do not have 2 step verification, and Imap already active.
but i cant seem to connect! do i need to have a google app account for this? just asking!

Comment: no need for google app try to edit the post and show your code for sending email it could be helpful

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear why you are doing this. If you are using gmail's MX, it means you're sending directly *to* a gmail user. Typically this will only be on port 25, but if you want encryption, just issue a STARTTLS after connecting. SSL on 465 and TLS on 587 are submission ports for outbound mail, so I'm not surprised you get an immediate 250 OK - you'd expect a 5.1.1 bounce later on. If you tried the same on the MX, I would expect it to fail up front.

Comment: thanks for the reply, the first objective is getting is 250 ok OR a no such user error. For other domains Im able to get this error on 465; again my code on MX => ssl://gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com:465 errors out with Connection timed out (110) and on ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465 the RCPT TO command says 250 Ok, where I should get no such user. ;; First Objective is still to get a error No such user where i there is no mailbox. So connecting on a 465 is what im trying first.

Comment: You're missing my point. You won't get a no such user from port 465 on smtp.gmail.com; you should use tls on port 25 on the MX instead.

Comment: actually on MX im getting connection error 110 on all 3 ports 587/ 465 and 25!

Comment: tried that still,  SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection timed out (110) => gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com:25

Comment: did that, all other domains are working, smtp.gmail.com seems to be working, just MX of gmail.com is not! not sure what to check any further.

Comment: do i need to create a SPF record for this?

Comment: SPF has nothing to do with this - you're not getting far enough for it to matter. This really looks like a network problem.

Comment: this is hostgator, i am able to traceroute to MX, but not telnet to it!!! which i presume is the issue.... hostgator says this is beyond their scope for spport :D , filed a support ticket,lets see. Can you recommend a host where this will work

Comment: They probably want you to use their mail server as a relay, that way they can keep a closer eye on things, i.e. spambots. I'd expect it to be covered in their docs - you're not the only one who wants to send email!